# Resolving database connection errors like this: [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

Tags: database, ubuntu, odbc, isql

What does this error typically mean?  I searched around for it on Google, but got a bunch of junk pages with no solutions or answers.

How can I go about resolving this particular error message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using the isql application that comes with the unixODBC driver manager? If you use 'isql -v YourDSN' you will get a more descriptive error message from either the driver manager or driver (whichever is causing the error).